#  C++ Linker error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, compiler-errors

I encounter a problem about LNK2019 when I compile my project with Visual Studio 2010. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

> gspan.obj : error LNK2019: 無法解析的外部符號 "public: class std::vector,class std::allocator >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > > __thiscall gSpan::tokenize(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?tokenize@gSpan@@QAE?AV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z) 在函式 "private: void __thiscall gSpan::read(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?read@gSpan@@AAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) 中被參考
>
> C:\Users\cool\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OGSPAN\Debug\OGSPAN.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 個無法解析的外部符號

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you source code, the method `gSpan::tokenize` is not implemented. It's called in `gSpan::read`. By the way, `gSpan::is_min` is not implemented too.

You can use `dumpbin.exe` to examine the generated `gspan.obj`. All other `gSpan::` methods are defined in `SECT??`(where `??` is two hex digits I think) sections, While `gSpan::tokenize` and `gSpan::is_min` are `UNDEF`.

To recreate the error, use this code:

```
class a {
public:
    void func1(void);
    void func2(void);
};

void a::func1(void)
{
    func2();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    a b;
    b.func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forget to implement tokenize in my code..., thanks for your help! Best :)

Answer (score 1):

[LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) means that one of your object files is referring to a symbol (function or variable name) that isn't defined in any of them.  Often it means that you declared and called a function, but forgot to actually implement the function.

Comment: If I'm reading that error correctly, it looks like it's the definition of void gSpan::read(std::string) that's missing.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You make me know the meaning of `LNK2019`! Best :)